# Java Lambdas: Comparator with PriorityQueue

Tags: java, lambda

Consider a priority queue

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
```

I can define a comparator in two ways here, one by using `lambda` and the other using the `Comparator()` class

Assuming a simple integer comparison of 2 variables for both these ways, I would like to know which variable is the value we want to compare and which variable contains the existing value from the queue

For exammple:

```
    PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
       @Override
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
            System.out.println(a+" "+b);
            return b-a;
        }
    });
```

When I call `heap.add(2)` followed by a `heap.add(3)`, the second `add()` call triggers the `compare(a,b)` function and prints `a=3 & b=2` which means that here, `a` has the new value and `b` is the existing value from the queue

Similarly, can you tell me if the below lambda expression will work similarly or is it the other way around ?

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>((a,b) -> b-a);
```

I know the question could have been written in much simpler manner but I just couldn't manage to do it at the moment.

Addtionally, these two print the same values i.e decreasing order 4,3,2,1

```
     PriorityQueue<Integer> heap2 = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
       @Override
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
            // System.out.println(a+" "+b);
            return b-a;
        }
    });
    
    PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(
        (a,b) -> b-a
    );
    
    heap.add(1);
    heap.add(2);
    heap.add(3);
    heap.add(4);
    
    heap2.add(1);
    heap2.add(2);
    heap2.add(3);
    heap2.add(4);
    
    while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(heap.poll()+" "+heap2.poll());
    }
```

Comment: The lambda is exactly the same as a Comparator instance. Why do you want to know which parameter is which?

Comment: When writing the comparator for a priority queue, you shouldn't care about "which parameter is the added element". If you somehow need to care about that, you're doing something wrong. Or are you just curious? In that case, it isn't guaranteed which is which.

Comment: Side note: Please don't implement integer comparators as `return b-a;` - that statement can overflow. Better use the predefined comparators provided by the API, e.g. [`Comparator.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder()) or [`Comparator.naturalOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder()), which also clearer communicates intent.

Comment: The `compare` method is defined to return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer if the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second argument, respectively. That's all that matters for an implementation of `Comparator`, whether that implementation is via a lambda expression, an anonymous class, or even a named class. It's up to the caller of the `compare` method to interpret the result correctly and react accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comments and answer everyone. I wrote `b-a` simply out of laziness, was aware of the overflow. As marstran mentioned, lambda expands out after compiling, this helped me understand everything better. Just curious to know. Thanks all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your two ways to define the `Comparator` are equivalent. Your lambda version actually expands to the other version after compiling, because `Comparator` is a functional interface.

Here's a third shorter way to define your `Comparator`, using a static factory method on the `Comparator` interface:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> heap3 = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```